# SCP command Clarification

Tags: linux, unix, scp

I'm using the scp commands to pull some files from the remote server and one variation of the command is not working.

I have 2 files names one.xml and two.xml in a remote server and I'm pulling these two files into the current dir using the following command:

```
scp stuadmin@10.44.220.112:/student/class/Intermediate/one.xml .
scp stuadmin@10.44.220.112:/student/class/Intermediate/two.xml .
```

The above command works fine but if I use wildcards to pull all the xml files in a single shot as shown below it returns `scp: No match.`

```
scp stuadmin@10.44.220.112:/student/class/Intermediate/*.xml .
```

Why is it working if I pull the files individually and not working if I try to pull using wildcards.

Comment: This may be more appropriate to ask on Super User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah this is for SuperUser. The answer is because the asterisk does a wildcard expansion FIRST before the command even runs. It is expanded by your SHELL. `echo *.xml` will really run `echo file1.xml file2.xml` and that is what echo sees, while bash sees the `*.xml`.

Since you are passing multiple files and paths to SCP, it gets confused as the first argument (or 2nd) is not a host:/path.

Put 'echo' in front of your command to see what is really being executed. You can't use wildcards on a remote host (unless you escape them first).

Comment: Say for eg if I have file1.xml and file2.xml in local then will they be overwritten if I use the command without escaping. And when you mentioned that "asterisk does a wildcard expansion FIRST before the command even runs" then expanding echo *.xml returns `echo: No match.` but you mentioned that it expands to `echo file1.xml file2.xml`. Can you elaborate on this.

Comment: In your case, no scp won't overwrite because it will give an error first. Your local shell will look for a filename beginning with `stuadmin...` and ending with `xml`. If echo says 'no match' that means there are no local files that match `*.xml`. `file1` & `file2` are examples.

Comment: In which case will it overwrite.

Answer (score -1):

You can clarify from these results

You can simplify this process a lot by tunneling ssh connections over other ssh connections (see this previous answer). The way I'd do it is to create an .ssh/config file on the LOCAL system with the following entries:

```
Host SYSTEM3
        ProxyCommand    ssh -e none SYSTEM2 exec /usr/bin/nc %h %p 2>/dev/null
        HostName        SYSTEM3.full.domain
        User            system3user

Host SYSTEM2
        ProxyCommand    ssh -e none SYSTEM1 exec /usr/bin/nc %h %p 2>/dev/null
        HostName        SYSTEM2.full.domain
        User            system2user

Host SYSTEM1
        HostName        SYSTEM1.full.domain
        User            system1user
```

(That's assuming both intermediate hosts have netcat installed as /usr/bin/nc -- if not, you may have to find/install some equivalent way of gatewaying stdin&stdout into a TCP session.)

With this set up, you can use scp SYSTEM3:/data /data on LOCAL, and it'll automatically tunnel through SYSTEM1 and SYSTEM2 (and ask for the passwords for the three SYSTEMn's in order -- this can be a little confusing, especially if you mistype one).